# Use assert in normal code

Tags: python, assert

I'm writing a python function to validate a token from an email. In the email, there is a url with the endpoint of it. I have two url parameters, the token and email address. In my endpoint I have to check :

- if the parameters are in the URL
- if there is a associate token in the database
- if it corresponds to the user email
- if the token is still valid (expires after 2 days)
- if it has already been used

I choose to wrap all those checks in a `try except` block, I will always return the same error "invalid token" so I don't have to precisely check individual error. I used the function `assertFalse` and `assertEqual` that will raise an exception if it's not correct.

```
try:
    # pull from url
    email = request.GET['email']
    value_token = request.GET['token']
    # test if valid
    token = EmailValidationToken.objects.get(token=value_token)
    assertFalse(token.consumed)
    assertEqual(email, token.user.email)
    assertFalse(token.is_expired())
except:
    pass # return error
```

I like the way I did it because it's super clean.
Is it a good practice ? Is there other solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, using `assert` for control flow rather than debugging is poor practice, because assertions can be turned off. Just use an ordinary `if` statement.

```
# pull from url
email = request.GET['email']
value_token = request.GET['token']
# test if valid
token = EmailValidationToken.objects.get(token=value_token)
if token.consumed or email != token.user.email or token.is_expired():
    pass # return error
```

If you absolutely insist on controlling your program's flow by raising an error (which is a valid thing to do in some cases), do so with `raise`, e.g. `if condition: raise TypeError`.